# When should log1p and expm1 be used?

Tags: floating-point

I have a simple question that is really hard to Google (besides the canonical *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic* paper).

When should functions such as `log1p` or `expm1` be used instead of `log` and `exp`? When should they not be used? How do different implementations of those functions differ in terms of their usage?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE! That's a very reasonable question, but would be easier to answer if you explained a bit *which* `log1p` you're referring to (especially how it's implemented, so we don't have to guess).

Comment: For real-valued arguments, log1p$(x)$ and expm1$(x)$ should be used when $x$ is small, e.g., when $1 + x = 1$ in floating point accuracy. See, e.g., http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html.

Comment: @ChristianClason thanks, I am referring mostly to C++ std or R, but as you ask I start to think that learning about differences in the implementations would be also very interesting.

Comment: Here's an example: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/compute-ex-1-x-near-x-0/8374#8374

Comment: Thanks for examples but the problem is that there are multiple examples available, but it is hard to find information about general rules and properties of those functions. Examples are not always easy to extrapolate.

Comment: @user2186862 "when $x$ is small" is correct, but not only "when $1+x=1$ in floating point accuracy" (which happens for $x\approx 10^{-16}$ in the usual double precision arithmetic). The documentation pages you linked show that they are useful already for $x\approx 10^{-10}$, for instance.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni yes, the $1+x == 1$ case was just an example.

Comment: Very interesting and useful answer. Thanks a lot. I was looking for this too. So just to confirm if we plot log1p() or log() in Python we will get the same shape of outcome, but a more accurate version if we use log1p()? My data has a lot of x<<1 values so makes sense to use log1p().

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We all know that
\begin{equation}
\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac12 x^2 + \dots
\end{equation}
implies that for $|x| \ll 1$, we have $\exp(x) \approx 1 + x$. This means that if we have to evaluate in floating point $\exp(x) -1$, for $|x| \ll 1$ catastrophic cancellation can occur.

This can be easily demonstrated in python:

```
>>> from math import (exp, expm1)

>>> x = 1e-8
>>> exp(x) - 1
9.99999993922529e-09
>>> expm1(x)
1.0000000050000001e-08

>>> x = 1e-22
>>> exp(x) - 1
0.0
>>> expm1(x)
1e-22
```

Exact values are
\begin{align}
\exp(10^{-8}) -1 &= 0.000000010000000050000000166666667083333334166666668 \dots \\
\exp(10^{-22})-1 &= 0.000000000000000000000100000000000000000000005000000 \dots
\end{align}

In general an "accurate" implementation of `exp` and `expm1` should be correct to no more than 1ULP (i.e. one unit of the last place). However, since attaining this accuracy results in "slow" code, sometimes a fast, less accurate implementation is available. <s>For example in CUDA we have `expf` and `expm1f`, where `f` stands for fast. According to the [CUDA C programming guide, app. D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#standard-functions) the `expf` has an error of 2ULP.</s>

If you do not care about errors in the order of few ULPS, usually different implementations of the exponential function are equivalent, but beware that bugs may be hidden somewhere... (Remember the [Pentium FDIV bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)?)

So it is pretty clear that `expm1` should be used to compute $\exp(x)-1$ for small $x$. Using it for general $x$ is not harmful, since `expm1` is expected to be accurate over its full range:

```
>>> exp(200)-1 == exp(200) == expm1(200)
True
```

(In the above example $1$ is well below 1ULP of $\exp(200)$, so all three expression return exactly the same floating point number.)

A similar discussion holds for the inverse functions `log` and `log1p` since $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for $|x| \ll 1$.

Comment: This answer was already contained in the comments to the OP question. However I felt useful to give a longer (although basic) account just for clarity, in the hope it will useful to some readers.

Comment: OK, but then one can simply conclude "so I can always use expm1 instead of exp"...

Comment: @tim your conclusion is wrong: you can always use `expm1(x)` instead of `exp(x)-1`. Of course `exp(x) == exp(x) - 1` does not hold in general.

Comment: OK, that is clear. And are there any clear cut criteria for $x \ll 1$?

Comment: @Tim there is no clear cut threshold, and the answer depends on the precision of the floating point implementation (and the problem being solved). While `expm1(x)` should be accurate to 1ULP over the entire range $0\leq x \leq 1$, `exp(x) - 1` progressively looses precision  from few ULP's when $x\approx 1$ to a complete breakdown when $x < \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is machine-epsilon.

Comment: "where `f` stands for fast" -- No, it stands for `float` as in the standard C math functions. The intrinsics are named like `__expf` and can also be accessed using fast math flags.

Comment: @JedBrown: thanks for pointing out my error. (Yes, my C/C++ skills are a little bit rusted...)

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the difference between `log` and `log1p` it might help to recall the graph if the logarithm:

[image: Logarithm]

If your data contains zeroes, then you probably don't want to use `log` since it's undefined at zero. And as $x$ approaches $0$, the value of $\ln(x)$ approaches $- \infty$. So if your $x$ values are close to $0$, then the value of $\ln(x)$ is potentially a large negative number. For example $\ln(\frac{1}{e}) = -1$ and $\ln(\frac{1}{e^{10}}) = -10$ and so on. This can be useful, but it can also distort your data towards large negative numbers, especially if your dataset also contains numbers much larger than zero.

On the other hand, as $x$ approaches $0$, the value of $\ln(x+1)$ approaches $0$ from the positive direction. For example $\ln(1+\frac{1}{e}) \sim 0.31$ and $\ln(1+\frac{1}{e^{10}}) \sim 0.000045$. So `log1p` produces only positive values and removes the 'danger' of large negative numbers. This generally insures a more homogeneous distribution when a dataset contains numbers close to zero.

In short, if the dataset is all greater than $1$, then `log` is usually fine. But, if the dataset has numbers between $0$ and $1$, then `log1p` is usually better.

Comment: I fully disagree with these arguments. There is no "danger" with negative values. If a problem asks you to compute the log of $10^{-24}$, this is what you have to do, full stop. And you speak as if one could trade log for log1p and conversely without compensating elsewhere in the process.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not talking about doing a homework problem. I'm talking about how to analyze data in a useful way. In the real world there are many data sets where having a zeros prohibits logarithmic analysis or having numbers close to zero distorts logarithmic analysis. In these situations it's standard practice to use `log1p` if adding one to the data is not qualitatively significant. That's a major reason why `log1p` exists in the first place.

Comment: Not at all. I wonder where you found this nonsense. The reason is avoidance of a catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Again it's standard data analysis. Perhaps the "avoidance of catastrophic cancellation" is another reason for `log1p`. But it's basically sidestepping unwanted zeros/poles either way.

Comment: This is used for $\log x$ close to $x=1$. Read the accepted answer and accept it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There's no contradiction between the accepted answer and mine. I'm just expanding on the logarithm aspect. Also the accepted answer doesn't say that `log1p` is for close to `x=1`. It says for `x<<1` which means close to `x=0`. Thus `log1p` is largely for avoiding zero/poles as I previously stated.

Comment: It seems that you don't want to hear my comment. I specified $\log x$ close to $x=1$ to avoid any ambiguity, which is obviously $\text{log1p }x$ close to $x=0$, but you skipped that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust TBH it's hard to make sense of your nonsense complaints. For the third time the main point is handling the zero/pole. Thanks for agreeing.

Comment: Moving away from the singularity by translation means that you don't care about accuracy as the modified values are not the true ones. In this case you use $\log(x+1)$, which is good enough. If you do care about accuracy, and are in the vicinity of $x=0$, $\log1p(x)$.

Comment: There is still hope that someday you will understand catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103627/discussion-between-sfmiller940-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Obviously $log1p \neq log$. There is still a chance that you'll stop wasting people's times with trolling pointless complaints.

Comment: Late to the party. Very clear and practical explanation. Thank you.

Comment: This post lacks context. I understand that e.g. in a machine learning pipeline it is common to use `log1p` as a [transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers), but this type of use is clearly very specific. Nobody would introduce an [intrinsic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) in C or C++ only for this type of use, since `log(x + 1)` would be sufficient to shift the argument away from the “dangerous” zone. IMHO `log1p(x)` is about reducing the rounding error for `x` close to zero, not for a handy transformation.