# Python: Underflow vs. exp of large negative numbers

Tags: python

Suppose I have values of log(P(x_i)), i.e. log-probabilities to events x_i. The probabilities are very small, so that these log-values are of the order of -1e3.

I want to compute an expectation value. In order to evaluate the corresponding sum, I need the probabilities P(x_i) themselves so I tried to call `numpy.exp`. This however, returns only 0 as the precision of basic floats in Python is not high enough to resolve a number like exp(-1000).

What is the typical way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your *final* result is of the order of magnitude of `exp(-1000)` $\approx 5 \cdot 10^{-435}$, then you are out of luck; no matter how you compute it, it will always underflow. There is simply no representable floating-point `binary64` number that small. The slower `Bigfloat`s are the only way out.

Some of the issues with large/small *intermediate* values, however, can be solved with a few manipulations:

- gathering and simplifying certain constants (the so-called [log-sum-exp trick](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/02/09/log-sum-exp/)).
- skillful use of the library functions [`log1p` and `expm1`](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/when-should-log1p-and-expm1-be-used).

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I will try to set up Bigfloat then.

Comment: Have you tried the log-sum-exp trick before abandoning the idea? It seems tailored to what you need.